# Run function on uncustomized input type

Tags: javascript

I have this sharepoint input:

```
<input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl40$g_b25debc7_4f96_4b4c_b4bc_f59036684958$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="Guardar" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ1')) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ctl40$g_b25debc7_4f96_4b4c_b4bc_f59036684958$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_b25debc7_4f96_4b4c_b4bc_f59036684958_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accesskey="O" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" target="_self">
```

I want to run function when I click it. But sharepoint added many properties and I cant add properties or change them to button.

How can I run this function when I click that button?

```
function sendEmail() {

    appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    var urlTemplate = appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    var fieldUsuario = ctx.CurrentItem.Notificar_x0020_a

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties' },
                'From': 'bocar@tbocar.onmicrosoft.com',
                'To': { 'results': [fieldUsuario] },
                'Body': 'Hello',
                'Subject': 'remember'
            }
        }
      ),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d.results;
            var i = result.length;
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in a `<script>` tag at some point after the button:

```
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"][accesskey="O"]');
button.addEventListener('click', function() { sendEmail(); });
```

This will keep both the original handler and add yours.

Comment: I do it, but it just dont executed, I put a breakpoint in debbuger but no hits

Comment: It return:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property  'AddEventListener' of null

Comment: It means `querySelector()` couldn't find the button, which probably means it doesn't exist yet. This script needs to run when the button in question has already been rendered on the page. I have no idea how your page is generated so I can't be more specific than that.